# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'game.map'; 'game' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[image]

I'm having a problem trying to run my Python project, as you can see in the image above. How can I get my project to run?

Comment: I know similar questions have been asked before, yet my problem seems to be different, as none of those solutions worked for me. Instead, maybe someone could come up with a better title, so the specific problem is more clear and others can find it easier.

Comment: Note that you should not add a screenshot of your code. You should instead copy and paste the relevent code in your question along with the error message (with proper code formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Python trying to import `map` from `game.py`.
You should rename folder `game` to `mygame`. After you can import like this `from mygame.map import Map`.